# jndi issue in tomcat to weblogic porting

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, weblogic, jndi, connection-pooling

I am trying to port a simple application (war file built in `eclipse`/`tomcat`) to `weblogic`. This application uses only one jdbc connection which in tomcat is specified in `context.xml` file. But the `context.xml` file is not part of war and therefore does not exist in weblogic. I tried creating `jdbc` connection from `weblogic` console, it connects fine. But this is the error i'm getting :

While trying to look up /comp/env/jndi/appconn in /app/webapp/app.war/925343129.; remaining name '/comp/env/jndi/appconn'

Usually in jdbc settings in `weblogic` "`jndi/appconn`" should work. I even tried "`/comp/env/jndi/appconn`" , but still getting the same error.

## Stack trace

```
ERROR - ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(220) | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/config/applicationContext-jndi.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up /comp/env/jndi/appconn in /app/webapp/app.war/1203652007.; remaining name '/comp/env/jndi/appconn'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1863)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3126)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1512)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:486)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:1267)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:409)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:143)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up /comp/env/jndi/appconn in /app/webapp/app.war/1203652007.; remaining name '/comp/env/jndi/appconn'
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ApplicationNamingNode.lookup(ApplicationNamingNode.java:144)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:393)
    at weblogic.jndi.factories.java.ReadOnlyContextWrapper.lookup(ReadOnlyContextWrapper.java:45)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.AbstractURLContext.lookup(AbstractURLContext.java:130)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 50 more
<May 15, 2014 6:12:55 PM BDT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/config/applicationContext-jndi.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up /comp/env/jndi/appconn in /app/webapp/app.war/1203652007.; remaining name '/comp/env/jndi/appconn'.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/config/applicationContext-jndi.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up /comp/env/jndi/appconn in /app/webapp/app.war/1203652007.; remaining name '/comp/env/jndi/appconn'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up /comp/env/jndi/appconn in /app/webapp/app.war/1203652007.; remaining name '/comp/env/jndi/appconn'
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ApplicationNamingNode.lookup(ApplicationNamingNode.java:144)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:393)
    at weblogic.jndi.factories.java.ReadOnlyContextWrapper.lookup(ReadOnlyContextWrapper.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<May 15, 2014 6:12:55 PM BDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1400155971699' for task '10'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: '
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1514)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:486)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up /comp/env/jndi/appconn in /app/webapp/app.war/1203652007.; remaining name '/comp/env/jndi/appconn'
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ApplicationNamingNode.lookup(ApplicationNamingNode.java:144)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:393)
    at weblogic.jndi.factories.java.ReadOnlyContextWrapper.lookup(ReadOnlyContextWrapper.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<May 15, 2014 6:12:55 PM BDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 7 task for the application 'abc'.> 
<May 15, 2014 6:12:55 PM BDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating start task for application 'abc'.> 
<May 15, 2014 6:12:55 PM BDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1514)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:486)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up /comp/env/jndi/appconn in /app/webapp/app.war/1203652007.; remaining name '/comp/env/jndi/appconn'
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ApplicationNamingNode.lookup(ApplicationNamingNode.java:144)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:393)
    at weblogic.jndi.factories.java.ReadOnlyContextWrapper.lookup(ReadOnlyContextWrapper.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<May 15, 2014 6:12:55 PM BDT> <Warning> <netuix> <BEA-423420> <Redirect is executed in begin or refresh action. Redirect url is /console/console.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=AppDeploymentsControlPage.>
```

Comment: Please post your full stacktrace.

Comment: To port from tomcat to weblogic make sure your application-jndi.xml file uses "jndi/appconn" instead of "java:/comp/env/jndi/appconn"